# Executing a Puppet Virtualhost with Apache2

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I have a server nearly running but when I execute the puppet file for the virtual host. I get:

```
Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.
```

I've tried modifying the apache2.conf file to change the ServerName and add the line:

```
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
```

I also tried commenting out the files with `mpm` lines in the /etc/apache2/mods-available/ directory. When I do this the problem disappears, but once I run puppet apply, the apache2.conf file goes back to its default settings.

What am I doing wrong? I've read many questions to solve the error above, but the apache2.conf rewrite to its default negates any changes I make.

Comment: I got the VirtualHost and server running without using puppet, but I'd be curious to know what's going on here.

Comment: Could you provide you puppet code that configures apache2 ?